# siunitx causing missing $ error

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am trying to typeset this table, but I keep running into the following error:

```
    ! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> $
l.34 ...{Global data expressed in \qty{e10}{\gram}
                                                  .\\%
```

My minimum working example is given below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=text}
\sisetup{range-phrase=--}
\sisetup{range-units=single}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\sisetup{detect-all}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{\cdot}}}
\sisetup{open-bracket=\, ,
                close-bracket=\,}
\sisetup{tight-spacing=true}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = ]\percent{\%}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Estimated biomass.}
\begin{tabular}{l c c }
\toprule
\textbf{Family}&\textbf{Global}&\textbf{Local}\\
\midrule
Family1&8.8&4.5\\
Family2&10.7&3.4\\
Family3&10.7&2.6\\
Family4&11.8&3.2\\
Family5&15.4&5.1\\
Family6&17.4&3.9\\
Family7&31.2&7.4\\         
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\footnotesize{Global data expressed in \qty{e10}{\gram}.\\%
Local data expressed in \qty{e8}{\gram}.%
}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When I comment out the siunitx parts of the text, things work fine. Is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: A more minimal example that still produces the error message: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=text, tight-spacing=true}

\begin{document}
Global data expressed in \qty{e10}{\gram}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Removing either `mode=text` or `tight-spacing=true` seems to solve the problem. Apparently these clash for some reason (maybe one forces text mode, whereas the other requires math mode).

Comment: Looks like a bug in v3  - I see the source, I just have to work out a good fix

Comment: @leandriss: My bad. I wasn't thinking straight when I posted this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by an ordering bug in `siunitx`: exactly how one deals with tight spacing and text mode is tricky. I've logged as https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/553. A temporary fix until that reaches CTAN:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=text, tight-spacing=true}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__siunitx_print_text_replace:n #1
  {
    \group_begin:
      \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:nNTF {#1} \mathchoice
        { \__siunitx_print_text_replace:Nnnnn #1 }
        {
          \tl_set:Nn \l__siunitx_print_tmp_tl {#1}
          \__siunitx_print_replace_font:N \l__siunitx_print_tmp_tl
          \cs_set:Npn \mathord ##1 {##1}
          \cs_set:Npn \pm { \exp_not:N \textpm }
          \cs_set:Npn \mp { \exp_not:n { \ensuremath { \mp } } }
          \cs_set:Npn \cdot { \exp_not:N \textperiodcentered }
          \cs_set:Npn \times { \exp_not:N \texttimes }
          \protected@edef \l__siunitx_print_tmp_tl { \l__siunitx_print_tmp_tl }
          \__siunitx_print_text_replace:N \l__siunitx_print_tmp_tl
          \tl_use:N \l__siunitx_print_tmp_tl
        }
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_gset_protected:Npx \__siunitx_print_text_replace:N #1
  {
    \exp_not:N \__siunitx_print_text_replace:NNn #1
      -
        { \exp_not:N \textminus }
      \char_generate:nn { `\_ } { 8 }
        { \exp_not:N \__siunitx_print_text_sub:n }
      ^
        { \exp_not:N \__siunitx_print_text_super:n }
      \exp_not:N \q_recursion_tail
        { ? }
      \exp_not:N \q_recursion_stop
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Global data expressed in $\qty{e10}{\gram}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's also an issue with some custom created units using `\DeclareSIUnit`. For example, `\DeclareSIUnit\mps{\meter/\second}` which produce the error `Undefined control sequence. \unit{\mps}`. I am still haven't updated to the most recent version of siunitx (15/10/2021) as it is still unavailable on CTAN. Hopefully, the update would resolve this issue as well. Thanks for every effort made in your package.

Comment: @hesham You've got a situation where you've mixed literal and macro units in a unit macro: this was never really supported and the changes in v3 mean it doesn't work. Either use a macro-based unit (`\metre\per\second`) in your abbreviation _or_ put in the literals you want (`m/s`).

Comment: I thought it was possible when I came across to test an old file of mine. But well you were right and the manual is pretty clear when I checked that part (page 14) "The ⟨symbol⟩ can contain literal input, other units, multiple prefixes, powers and `\per`, although literal text should not be intermixed with unit macros," which was actually there even before v3.